# SQL How to get value of XML data column and use it inside of the where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a table with an `XML` data type column called `Settings`. The structure of the `XML` data:

```
<root>
<Setting1>true</Setting1>
<Setting2>false</Setting2>
...
<root>
```

The table also has an `ID` column that I would like to use to group my results. I want to count how many `Setting1` configurations are set to `true` per `ID`. **Note: The `ID` field is not unique and can repeat.**

Here is what I have so far:

```
with xmlnamespaces (DEFAULT '...')
select count(Setting1) as counts
  from (select Settings.value('(/root/Setting1)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Setting1
    from MY_TABLE
    group by ID) res
  where Setting1= 'true'
```

However I am getting the following error:

> Column 'MY_TABLE.Configuration' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you've got an answer already, I'd like to add some alternatives:

*(Credits to Michal Turczyn for the mockup)*

```
declare @tbl table (id int, xmlCol xml);
insert into @tbl values
(1, '<root>
<Setting1>true</Setting1>
<Setting2>false</Setting2>
</root>'),
(1, '<root>
<Setting1>true</Setting1>
<Setting2>false</Setting2>
</root>'),
(2, '<root>
<Setting1>false</Setting1>
<Setting2>false</Setting2>
</root>'),
(2, '<root>
<Setting1>true</Setting1>
<Setting2>false</Setting2>
</root>');
```

The fastest should be a simple `XML.exist()`:

```
SELECT t.id,
       sum(CASE WHEN t.xmlCol.exist('/root/Setting1[text()="true"]')=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) howManyTrue
FROM @tbl t
GROUP BY t.id
```

You can enhance this with a variable to set the SettingName outside the statement:

```
DECLARE @SettingName NVARCHAR(100)=N'Setting1';

SELECT t.id,
       sum(CASE WHEN t.xmlCol.exist('/root/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@SettingName") and text()="true"]')=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) howManyTrue
FROM @tbl t
GROUP BY t.id
```

--And if a Setting might occur more than once within one XML, you might use XQuery's `count()`:

```
SELECT t.id,
       sum(t.xmlCol.value('count(/root/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@SettingName") and text()="true"])','int')) howManyTrue
FROM @tbl t
GROUP BY t.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
declare @tbl table (id int, xmlCol xml);
insert into @tbl values
(1, '<root>
<Setting1>true</Setting1>
<Setting2>false</Setting2>
</root>'),
(1, '<root>
<Setting1>true</Setting1>
<Setting2>false</Setting2>
</root>'),
(2, '<root>
<Setting1>false</Setting1>
<Setting2>false</Setting2>
</root>'),
(2, '<root>
<Setting1>true</Setting1>
<Setting2>false</Setting2>
</root>');

select id,
       sum(convert(int, xmlCol.value('(/root//Setting1/node())[1]', 'bit'))) howManyTrue
from @tbl
group by id
```

Comment: Amazingly enough, the node() function is not documented: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-functions-against-the-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Your answer is working fine (+1 from my side), but I have some remarks: 1) This does not need the *deep search* before `//Setting1`. And 2), this works without the `/node()` as well...  And 3) better than reading **all** values I'd prefer `XML.exist()` or the XQuery's `count()` (see my answer).

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Do you know any specific case, where `node()` is actually needed? It might help in complex FLWOR-queries, but I did not need it anywhere up to now...

Comment: @Shnugo, same here. I didn't know it exists. And never needed it.

Comment: @Shnugo, what bothers me - it is not documented.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky That's because `/node()` is not XQuery function but a XPath [node test](https://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial/xpath_node_test.cfm)

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Hi again, [this seems to be the docs you are missing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/path-expressions-specifying-node-test?view=sql-server-2019)